# Pytest does not recognize new command line option

Tags: python, selenium, testing, pytest

In my conftest.py I added following code

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--browser_name", action="store", default="chrome"
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    browser_name = request.config.getoption("--browser_name")
    if browser_name == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    elif browser_name == "Edge":
        driver = webdriver.Edge()
    driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/")
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()
```

I want to choose browser name from command line, but pytest does not recognize it when I run my tests by `pytest --browser_name firefox`. What might be the problem?
ERROR message:

```
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --browser_name
  inifile: None
  rootdir: /home/*****/PycharmProjects/SeleniumFramework
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly an issue with how you're using the fixture, or the location of you're conftest. Perhaps you have an issue with your version of `pytest`? The following works with `pytest-4.6.9`

`conftest.py`

```py
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser_name", action="store", default="chrome")


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    if (browser_name := request.config.getoption("--browser_name")) == "chrome":
        print("chrome")
    else:
        print("Not chrome")
```

`test_foo.py`

```py
def test_foo(setup):
    pass
```

Then with `pytest test_foo.py -s --browser_name="firefox"` I get

```bash
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                  

test_foo.py Not chrome
.

===================== 1 passed in 0.07 seconds =========================
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved - I didn't have Firefox installed on my Desktop. After installation and environment restart everything works fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33939034)